# How can I get a transparent background for a DataForm in Silverlight 3?

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I can't seem to get a transparent background for a DataForm in Silverlight 3 beta.  The code below is what I am trying but it only makes the background partially transparent.  Is there something I can do to fix it?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Orange">
    <Border Background="Blue" Margin="100,0,0,100"/>
    <Controls:DataForm x:Name="dataform" Background="Transparent" Margin="30"/>
</Grid>
```

[Screenshot http://www.portnine.com/data/images/Misc/silverlight3.jpg](http://www.portnine.com/data/images/Misc/silverlight3.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the DataForm starts "Disabled" which means the corresponding Visual State alters the appearance.

If you override the default control template you will find a static resource named "DisabledColor". This is creating the slightly opaque white you are seeing. Just change that and you will be fine.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledColor" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
```